# Ipad rotation - move only status bar

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation

I'm developing some game and I"m dealing with Ipad rotation.
What I need to do on rotation it's just move status bar position, but view itself don't need to change!

How can i do that?
thanks

Comment: you have to change the view because the statusbar is not part of the view ... the size of your view changes from 1004x768 to 1024x748

Comment: Ok, but then I need to keep all objects at the same places like it was before the rotation.. How can i do it? Thanks!